# how to avoid XMLHttpRequest callback hell in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, xmlhttprequest, settimeout

I need to use the response from two different API calls to construct my model, and I do not want to make nested callbacks. the idea is to make two separate calls then wait for until both calls have responded then call the model function

```
    let data = null
    let forecast = null
    const dataRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
    dataRequest.responseType = 'json';
    dataRequest.open('GET', urlData)
    dataRequest.send()
    dataRequest.onload = () => data = dataRequest.response


    const forecastRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
    forecastRequest.responseType = 'json';
    forecastRequest.open('GET', urlForecast)
    forecastRequest.send()
    forecastRequest.onload = () => forecast = forecastRequest.response
  

setTimeout(
        function () {
          const theModel = model(data, forecast) // data,forecast are null
        }, 0); // this will work if I set the waiting time to 100 instead of 0
```

the problem is in that the sequence of the execution does not behave as expected.
In the documentation, it is stated clearly that when using the setTimeout method or any other asynchronous call, the function will be inserted in the event queue. So, in my application, the first onload method will be inserted first to the event queue, then the second onload will be inserted, and finally, the setTimeout will be the last method to be inserted (so I am expecting that it will be the last one to be executed as well). But the execution sequence shows something different: the setTimeout function will be executed first even though the setTimeout is the last one in the queue and it should be the last one to be executed
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: Try to use the fetch API with "await". It will be something like: const resp1 = await fetch(urlData); const data = await resp1.json(); const resp2 = await fetch(urlForecast); const forecast = await resp2.json();

Answer (score 0):

So you want to do one after the another? Why not make the second request after the first onload event, and the model after the second onload?

```
let data = null
let forecast = null
let theModel = null

const dataRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()

dataRequest.responseType = 'json';
dataRequest.open('GET', urlData)
dataRequest.send()
dataRequest.onload = () => {

        data = dataRequest.response;

        const forecastRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
        forecastRequest.responseType = 'json';
        forecastRequest.open('GET', urlForecast)
        forecastRequest.send()
        forecastRequest.onload = () => {

                forecast = forecastRequest.response;

                theModel = model(data, forecast);

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Charly, but that is exactly what I want to avoid, I do not want to make nested callbacks. The reason for that is that I do not want the second call to be dependent on the first one. What happens in your example if the first call fails? , you will never get the chance to call onload for the second call.

Comment: yes but your setTimeout will be ready first when you set it to 0 and when you don't wait the the xhr results

Comment: and if one of the xhr calls fails you can handle the error with xhr.onerror = function() { // only triggers if the request couldn't be made at all
};

Comment: you actually have a point here, but I still did not understand the execution sequence, what is it I am not understanding correctly from the event queue? setTimeout(func(),0) should always be the last one to be executed even if I set it to 0. This is the point of the timeout, why else would I use it to simulate an asynchronous behaviour every time people demonstrate asynchronous programming in JavaScript

Comment: The execution start time of the timeout is the last one yes, but it is ready before the XML requests when you set it to 0. Because the XML requests take more time to finish than the timeout.

Comment: I know that it will take more time to execute the XMLHttpRequest, and the timeout will be ready before that. But I was expecting that the timeout method will be blocked by the httpRequest methods in the event queue.It does not happen that way apparently and that what makes me confused. can you please explain me why it is not blocked by the http requests?